# Can I customize a textarea to allow me to add/remove specific text items?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to be able to show additional text in a textarea, like so :.

[image]

The cursor would not be able to go "behind" the label "some text", and clicking on the small cross would remove it.

Is there a jquery plugin that does that ?

**EDIT** : I figured it couldn't be a "real" textarea. Is it possible to render "editable" a div ?

Comment: http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: @Sarfraz He wanted into text area. your example is a plugin which emulate input controls....

Comment: I'd change your title - it doesn't really cover what you are _actually_ asking, which seems to be - "Can I customize a textarea to allow me to add/remove specfic text items" - or something like that. Not necessarily anything to do with a DIV.

Comment: TEXTAREA can only have Replaceable character data. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/textarea.html  Use of HTML isn't going to work.  It will just show up as actual text (ie. it will look like HTML code, not rendered/styled HTML).  You'll need to do something more fancy like @Sarfraz link

Comment: @Sarfraz: that should be an answer. Awesome effects

Comment: @RoyiNamir: That's a project for him, not us.  That link would be a good way to get started.

Comment: http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: Yes I know about chosen, that's where I printscreened the label to make the picture :)

Comment: @Rocket I'm just asking for a general direction; also maybe someone on the web already has a plugin that does that. I'm trying not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Manu: You should specify that in the question, not just say "I want this."

Comment: So what you guys are saying is that I should steal the code from Chosen ? :p

Comment: @Rocket sorry if I came off rude, that was not my intent.

Comment: @Manu: Yep, it's open source :-)

Comment: @Manu: It wasn't that you were rude, it's that you didn't show any effort/research.

Comment: well that's just not true, I did a picture :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Textarea` elements may only contain text, they may not contain other HTML elements.

I know you've probably seen this effect elsewhere on the web, and I would guess that what you're seeing in most cases is a complex structure of HTML that is carefully crafted to LOOK like a `textarea`.

Most likely, this is another element (possibly a `div`), and inside that you have any other elements stacking to the left, and an `input` element (not a `textarea`) with it's borders, padding, etc removed so that you can't see it against the fake `textarea` background.  That could achieve the same thing for which you're looking.

If you really think about it, it doesn't make much sense to use a real `textarea` for this problem anyway, since I am guessing you don't want them entering an entire paragraph, just a few words for each entry.  In which case, an `input` of type text is more appropriate.

Comment: Yes, I figured as much... Using an <input> is a nice idea, even though I'd like to keep it multiline

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is : no, you can't.

As @Slobaum said, the effect you want to reproduce is made using a `div` to fake a real `textarea`. There is a bunch of plugins for that specific behavior. I recently used TextboxList, wich works quite well. Costs 20$ though.

http://www.devthought.com/projects/mootools/textboxlist/

Comment: Just on initial look, that looks like a fairly feature-rich list tool.  Speaking from experience, you can really get into a mess (and a serious time-sink) if you're working with a crappy list tool.  In the right scenario, I'd say it's worth $20 in your wasted time alone.

Comment: view-source => copy => paste :-P (ps dont do this)... EDIT: `You can use and modify TextboxList freely for any non-commercial use.` :-D

Comment: @Rocket I used to do that pretty often myself :)  Now that I'm working for a fairly large company that's actually profitable, it behooves us to keep it all legal.  And I'm telling you, my boss would shell out $20 to save a couple hours time without thinking twice.

Answer (score 1):

No. Textarea is only for plain text.